# Make [web-browser] a synonym of [browser], or redefine [browser]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

It does make sense to keep the two tags separate if [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser) is used in more general terms (for example, the `man` command as an offline, command-line-based documentation browser).

The way the [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser) tag is defined now (and if we're happy with that Internet-centric definition), then [web-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) should be made a synonym of [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser):

> A web browser is a software application for retrieving, presenting,
>   and traversing information resources on the World Wide Web

Comment: By [tag:web-browser], I assume you mean the same as [tag:http-client], no?

Comment: @tchrist that's another candidate for turning into a synonym, although to me a (web-)browser always has a GUI, whereas an http-client can be something like `curl` or `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: Most people think of *lynx* as a web browser, and it has no GUI.

Comment: @tchrist You're right, didn't think of that one. So maybe all 3 should be synonyms? I have mixed feelings about [http-client], but [browser] and [web-browser] should definitely merge.

Comment: @tchrist: I'd consider lynx to have the console equivalent to a GUI. In my opinion, the difference between [http-client] and [web-browser] is that http-client takes a request, executes it then shuts down, while the web-browser launches, takes a request, executes it, *shows it to the user* and waits for navigation instructions.  In short, http-client is only a client that gets things from an http server and web-browser actually lets the user browse the web

Comment: Are we happy with a definition that says that a web browser is *interactive*?

Comment: Also, the `man` command *isn't* a browser, but the `info` command arguably is.

Comment: What about "Class Browsers" and the like? Even though the `web-browser` is the overwhelmingly dominant user of the word `browser`, it really isn't the only one.

Comment: @Deduplicator Wouldn't a class browser fall under `IDE`? I agree that there are other uses of the word `browser`, but as it's defined in the tag wiki, it's clearly referring to web browsers only. Other software that may be considered a browser can be referred to using different terms, so my vote is to stick with `[browser]` as referring explicitly to web (including `lynx` and the like).

Comment: The difference between [browser] and [http-client] is that the first is a captive user interface (graphical, text or whatever), while the latter can be a library, have a CLI or be otherwise non-interactive.

Comment: I can perfectly imagine an http-client that is not a browser. Any REST client would do. And boy they are many.

Comment: The suggestion is to make `web-browser` and `browser` synonyms. The `http-client` discussion is tangential.

Comment: @tchrist nop. You probably never heard of [Gopher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_(protocol)).

Comment: @Knu Guess again